# How to intuit, construe multiplicands and multiplicators $\le 10$ resulting from $\binom pc$, WITHOUT division or factorials?

Tags: combinatorics

I grok, am NOT asking about, the answers below. Rather —  **how can I deduce and intuit the multiplicands and multiplicators $\le 10$,  resulting from simplifying $\dbinom {p \text{ people}}{c\text{-person committee}}$  DIRECTLY?**  ***WITHOUT division or factorials!***

### Orange underline

1. Unquestionably, $\color{darkorange}{4 \times 3/2 = 3!}$. But how can I construe, intuit $\color{darkorange}{3!}$ DIRECTLY? Note  that $\color{darkorange}{3!}$ wasn't one of the original numbers (2, 4). What does $\color{darkorange}{3!}$  mean?

***Here's my surmisal.*** [Blitzstein's solution hints to this calculation, but he didn't write 3! explicitly](https://math.codidact.com/posts/282608). You fix the first person. Then of the 3 people left, you can pick the 2nd person in your 2-person committee in 3 ways. Did I surmise correctly?

### Red underline

2. Unquestionably, $\color{red}{\dfrac{8 \times 7 \times 6}{3!}  = 8 ×  7}$. But how can I construe, intuit $\color{red}{8 ×  7}$ DIRECTLY? Note that $\color{red}{7 } $ wasn't one of the original numbers of 3 or 8. What does $\color{red}{7 } $ mean?

***Here's my surmisal.*** You can pick the 1st committee member in $\color{red}{8} $ ways, and  the 2nd member in $\color{red}{7} $ ways. Then can't you pick the 3rd member in 6 ways? By this Constructive Counting (David Patrick, p 38 bottom), the answer ought be  8 × 7 × 6? Why didn't 6 appear as a multiplicator?

> **Problem 4.1:**
>
> (b) In how many ways can a 2-person committee be chosen from a group of 4 people (where the
> order in which we choose the 2 people doesn't matter)?
>
> [image: Image alt text]

David Patrick, [BS Math & Computer Science, MS Math (Carnegie Mellon),  PhD Math (MIT)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/David_Patrick). *Introduction to Counting & Probability* 2005, pp 66-7.

### Examples 3 and 4

3. I know [the ways to form a committee of 2 from 8](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/calculate-ways-to-form-a-committee-of-3-from-8-directly-without-%C3%B7.295777/post-975751) $= \dbinom8 2 = \dfrac{8\cdot7}{2!} =  \color{violet}{4 × 7}.$ But how can I construe, intuit $\color{violet}{4 × 7}$ DIRECTLY?  Note that $\color{violet}{4, 7}$ aren't the original numbers of 2, 8.
4. I know [the ways to form a committee of 3 from 10](https://mathforums.com/threads/calculate-ways-to-form-a-committee-of-3-from-8-directly-without-%C3%B7.362347/post-664313) $=  \dbinom {10} 3 = \dfrac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{3!} =  \color{springgreen}{10 × 3 × 4}.$ But  how can I construe, intuit $\color{springgreen}{10 × 3 × 4}$ DIRECTLY?   I'm surmising that $\color{springgreen}{10}$ refers to the original 10, and $\color{springgreen}{3}$ to the chosen 3. But what does $\color{springgreen}{4}$ mean?

Comment: In your example 4, your green 3 is simply 9/3 and the green four is 8/2. There is nothing else going on. For example when you calculate $\binom{12}3$ you get $4\times11\times5$. Out of the original numerator $12\times11\times10$ only the the first is divisible by three, so you cannot cancel the $3$ from the denominator using any other factor in the numerator. Similarly, in $$\binom{15}3=\frac{15\times14\times13}{3\times2\times1}=5\times7\times13.$$ No other way, because $15$ is the only factor divisible by three and $14$ the only divisible by two.

Comment: All I'm saying is that divisibility to a great extent ties your hands, and there is nothing DIRECT about which factor is cancelled against which.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I grok all this divisibility. But is there no way to construe, intuit $5 × 7 × 13$ directly? What do 5, 7, 13 mean? 5 ways from what? What event yielded 7 ways? What other event yielded 13 ways?

Comment: No *universal* recipe. $\binom{17}3$ forces $17\times8\times5$. You see that which of the three factors in $\binom n3$  is divided by three depends on the residue class of $n$ modulo $3$. Therefore there cannot be a recipe that would work for all $n$. Why do you think that there should be a general interpretation of the factors that remain after cancellation?